# View loop value doesn't change after first value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, loops

I have an `ICollection<String>` being passed to my view and I do a foreach to load a partial view. It loops through the correct number of times, however, the value it passes is the same and I know in the model that this is not the case.

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index", new List<String>());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(List<String> txtValue)
    {
        return View("Index", txtValue);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
        <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<List<String>>" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Deletes the div the Control is in.
    $(".delete").live("click", function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    //Adds the TextBoxes to divControls
    function AddTextBox(Value) {
        var elements = "<div><input name=\"txtValue\" type=\"text\" /><input type=\"button\" class=\"delete\" value=\"-\" /><br/></div>";
        $("#divControls").append(elements);
    }
    </script>

<h2>Controls!!!</h2>
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" name="Refresh" value="+" onclick="AddTextBox()" />
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
    <input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="Submit" />
    <div id="divControls">
<%  
        foreach (var text in this.Model)
        { %>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtValue", text, new { id = "Value", name = "txtValue" })%>
           <% Html.RenderPartial("TextControl", text);
        }
%>
    </div>
<% 
    } 
%>
</asp:Content>
```

**TextControl.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<String>" %>

<div>
    <%=Html.TextBox("txtValue", this.Model, new { id = "Value", name = "txtValue" }) %>
    <input id="btn" type="button" class="delete" value="-" /><br/>
</div>
```

The values of the model passed from the controller to the view are correct, even when passed to the user control "TextControl" the value is correct, but when the Textbox displays they are all just the first value of the original model passed in.

Ex.

```
Model as List<String> { "1", "2", "3", "4" }
```

passed to the view, will iterate through each one correctly, passing the correct string to "TextControl" to create a `Html.TextBox("name", this.Model)`. Everything on the debugging side appears correct, however, when it finishes all the textboxes are "1" (or the first value in the list).

Here's a link to my exact code: http://www.sendspace.com/file/sypl1u

**Note:**
I came up with a solution of just using `<input type="text" name="txtValue" value="<%= this.Model %>" />` instead.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you saying, that i doesn't increment?

Comment: `i` definitely increments.  The problem has to be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: can you show the content of TextControl view?

Comment: So you have debugged your code on the return View statement in the action to examine txtValue? If yes, can you post it here please.

Comment: txtValue is the value I put into the textboxes and it does return different values but then when the page refreshes it loads the textboxes with only the first value. this.Model.ElementAt(0) when txtValue[0] != txtValue[1]

could it be something to do with the fact everything is a pointer in C#?

Comment: Have you tried just outputting `this.Model.ElementAt(i)` instead of passing it to the TextControl?  That would eliminate the TextControl as a source of failure.

Comment: That still does the same thing. So TextControl isn't the problem.
I'm almost certain it has to do with the loop I just don't know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: The only answer left is that your Model's data is wrong.  Are you sure it's correct?  CAn you post the code that generates it?

Comment: Well, If I put a break right at the return It has the correct values. So unless for some random reason it's changing between the return and the view it has to be the correct values. I'll post my full page but I don't see how it could be changing.

The values are what I place into the textboxes I create with my JQuery which I pass to the controller as List/Collection. And before the Controller returns them, they are correct so I have no idea why they place back into the textboxes wrong.

Comment: Please provide a small but complete sample project that reproduces this behavior.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Where should I upload it too? is there a way to attach files to here?

Comment: It's wierd because I debugged through the whole thing and when it hits the for loop the value changes and it passes it correctly but then just doesn't print the correct value. I'm baffled.

Comment: `<%=Html.TextBox("txtValue", text, new { id = "Value", name = "txtValue" })%>`   You're setting every textbox to have the same id.

Comment: I changed it to <%=Html.TextBox("txtValue", this.Model, new { id = this.Model, name = "txtValue" }) %> and it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Potential issue: you are using `ElementAt` which is LINQ method that fave special behavior for IList argument, but you are passing in `txtValue` as result of some query. In this case `ElementAt` may case sequence to be enumerated multiple times and may even fail if sequence can't be re-enumerated.

Consider simple `foreach` on the collection instead:

```
    foreach (var text in Model)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("TextControl", text);
    }
```

Comment: Nope, That still does the same thing as the regular for loop.